# Displayed HTML is shown with Tags

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to display content, formatted with HTML.

But instead it gets displayed with HTML tags.

I just get the content from the database and put it inside a `<div>`.

This is an image displaying the issue:
[image: An image displaying the issue]

Comment: What are you using to output the data? Rails, PHP, etc?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Spacebars`, [you can use triple braces to insert raw HTML](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#triple-braced-tags):

```
{{{content}}}
```

Comment: though i didn't add Spacebars, your comment reminded me that triple braces can be used to insert raw HTML.

Thank you.

Comment: Just beware that this opens up an xss vector. Make sure you trust your html.